# Change sheet on multiple Excel documents from "Visible" to "Very Hidden"

Tags: python, excel, vba

I need help modifying one sheet from multiple documents, the sheets the same name in between all the documents, from visible to becoming "Very Hidden". I know how to do this in VBA only for one document at a time but I do not know how to do it to many.

I need to do this over 100 times so it would be great if anyone knew how to code this either using VBa or Python (maybe using "openpyxl" in Python 2?)

Thank you

Comment: What on earth is "Very Hidden"? Is it different from just normal "Hidden"?

Comment: @SiHa the worksheet object has a `.Visible` state which can be either of three constants: `xlSheetVisible`, `xlSheetHidden` and `xlSheetVeryHidden`. The "Very Hidden" sheet is not visible in the Hide/Unhide sheets UI and can only be unhidden programmatically.

Comment: @DavidZemens Useful info, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a list (`files`) representing the file paths for each of the 100+ files.

```
from win32com import Client
files = ["path/to/file1.xlsx", "path/to/file2.xlsx"] 
xl = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

map(hide, files)

xl.Quit()

def hide(file):
    SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"  # The name of the sheet you want to hide
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(file)
    wb.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME).Visible = 2 # xlSheetVeryHidden
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
```

NOTE: If you don't want to expressly write the list of files directly in your .py, you need some other way of identifying them and reading them in to a list object. Ultimately, you need a list of these file names, *or* you need some way of programmatically deriving the file names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there any way on which I won't need to list the path to the 100+ documents? (on the "file" field?)

Comment: Probably, what have you tried so far? You've given pretty much no detail about where these files exist, or how the list of files could be derived (i.e., from reading a directory, etc.)

Comment: The files are inside a folder on my desktop..

C:/Users/arancela/Desktop/TEST/

The files all start with "MM_" and then have numbers from 1 to 300, however, the naming conventions for the numbers were nor done on 3 digits, so they don't follow an organized pattern besides having the same first 3 characters.

The Sheet I want to change is called "Lists"

Thank you for all your help

Comment: OK, well then that is a separate question and should be asked as such. I'm not going to teach you everything there is to know about python, when you asked for a py solution, I have to assume that you know basic stuff like this. If you don't, ask a new question. The answer I posted is one possible solution to your original question: "I do not know how to do it [set sheet to VeryHidden] to many."  So, once you figure it out, try my answer and if it works, mark as accepted. Cheers & good luck.